# Installing MySQL for Python on Cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, mysql-python

I am new to Python and I apologize in advance for asking for help on this trivial matter. I installed `Python 2.14.7` on `Cygwin` running on `Win 10`, and would like to install `MySQL` (for python) and the `MySQLdb` library to play around. I searched the net for the exact installation steps but did not find a conclusive answer. Can anyone please point me to any resources (download links & installation Steps) that might help me in this endeavor ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

So, MySql is a database. You don't install a database for Python. It's a standalone software. You can install any version of it that compatible with cygwin. What you do need is a Python database connector, which can be downloaded at Oracle.com. (sorry I am answering with my phone maybe you need to Google it yourself.) 
You should Google it and register an account on Oracle.com. Then it's good to download the lib.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Cygwin versions of MySqL and of Python, you can 
follow the instruction at

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp

an after installing the cygwin package `python2-pip` by cygwin setup, install the connect through pip

```
python -m pip install mysql-connector
```